# ASP.NET/MVC3 - solution for user-customized reports without developer intervention

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Are there any libraries or solutions (third party, open source or commercial) that allow users to create their own reports, which would be accessible from the front-end, without developers' intervention (for most cases?)

Basically, we are using Entity Framework as the ORM. The application will collect stats such as transactions between users, which pages on the site have been visited, and by which user. We have to come up with an interface that allow an administrator to come up with reports which are basically joins between tables. Adding to the difficulty is that the user is able to come up with reports on the fly without messing around with the code.

We would like the user to go through the ORM for those reports, so writing raw SQL statements is out of the question. Is there any ways to let users define their own custom 'views' of a database to generate reports?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more please?

Comment: I have added more details in comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about to let user write his own linq query? Or [sql that would be executed with entity](http://www.nakov.com/blog/2011/01/12/native-sql-queries-in-entity-framework/) framework?

Linq can be written as string and executed also. Look at this nice [tutorial](http://blog.nakedobjects.net/?p=72). You could make some nice editor yourselves to hide query language from user.

Comment: Would the native SQL be database-independent?

Comment: I would say that if you write it that way (using SQL3 (SQL-99)) then it will be. There are different providers for lets say oracle and others.... in order for EF to work.